# Apples and Infinity

Tags: infinity, paradoxes

I am taking a proof writing and discrete mathematics course and we are learning about infinity. My TA asked me the following question and I'm wondering if my solution is correct? 

**Question:**
Suppose Person A has infinitely many apples and Person B has ${0}$ apples. Person A wants to play a game with Person B in which there are infinitely many rounds. In each round Person A gives Person B ${10}$ apples and Person B gives ${1}$ back. What is the least number of apples Person B must have at the end of the game?

**My Solution:**

Zero is the minimum. There is a way to play in which Person B will have ${0}$ apples: Suppose (to start) all of the apples that Person A has are labeled 1 to ${\infty}$. In round one Person A gives apples labeled ${1-10}$ to Person B, in round two ${21-30}$, and so on... Further, in each round Person B gives back the apple labeled with that round number: i.e. in round one he returns the Apple Labeled ${1}$, etc...
My thought is that Person B will have ${0}$ apples at the end because if anyone disagrees, they'd have to say B has at least one apple. But which apple would B have? The apple labeled ${1000}$? No B handed that back in round one-thousand. The apple labeled ${1000000}$? No, B handed that back in round one million. And so on such that B has no apples.

Comment: Looks good to me.

Comment: Is Person A allowed to give back the same apples?

Comment: I kinda have a problem with the question. If the game as infinitely many rounds, when is "the end of the game?"

Comment: @mapierce271 that can easily be solved by setting the duration of the $n$-th round to last $1/2^n$ minutes. The problem with the question is deeper.

Comment: @BrandonCarter No, it explicitly states which apples Person A will give to Person B and it will never be the same apple that B gave back - i think.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a terrible question. Firstly, it speaks of infinity but seems to mean countable, reinforcing the false idea that infinity is a number and that there is just one infinity. Secondly, it is not a mathematical question but rather a philosophical metaphysical question. Here is a similar situation: suppose a light switch is switched at time intervals $1/2^n$, for each $n$, counting in minutes let's say. Every time the switch is switched, a light bulb changes between on and off. The process will end after precisely $2$ minutes. Is the light on or off after 3 minutes? Does it matter if the light was initially on or off?

This is a metaphysical question, not a mathematical one. If you try to model it mathematically it becomes very clear. Initially the light is either on or off, signified by $1$ or $0$, respectively. Then the entire process is clearly modeled by an alternating sequence of $0$ and $1$. So we have the sequence $(s_n)_{n\ge 1}$ of which we know is an alternating sequence, and we seem to ask what is $s_\infty $. Well, the answer is that this is a nonsensical question. The situation after the process was done was never modeled, so it's not there. Interpreting $s_\infty $ as a limit does not help either. If you try to add the final state of the light into the model you run into the physical problem of actually modeling a manifestly physically impossible scenario.

Comment: But Hilbert's Hotel is also physically impossible, but it is mathematical in the sense that it gives us insight into problems with believing infinity is a really big number. I agree the problem is looking for "countable" rather than infinity since everything is discrete. But do you think my reasoning that Person B has as low as 0 apples is at least valid?

Comment: With Hilbert's hotel it's the mathematics translated into a nice story. Here you have a story and try to solve it mathematically. And it's not so much that your answer is not valid as much as the question is not a question.